# VideoJS is not defined when load from ajax

Tags: jquery, video.js

I'm using self-hosted videojs 7.1.

I have a page that list a lot of thumbnails, and if you click on any thumbnail, it will load the video source from ajax, and play the video in bootstrap modal dialog.

page HTML

```
<link href="/css/videojs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/videojs.7.1.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <?php foreach($ids as $id){ ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="/path/to/thumbnail-<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg">
            <div>some description here</div>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-play" data-vdoid="<?php echo $id; ?>">Play video</a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="modal fade modal-wide" id="dialog-play" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialogLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body nomargin">
                <div id="dialog-play-content">Loading...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

page JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
    $('.btn-play').click(function(){
            var vdoid = $(this).data('vdoid');
            $.get( "/vdo/player?vdoid="+vdoid, function(data){
                $("#dialog-play-content").html(data);
                $("#dialog-play").modal('show');
            });
            return false;
     });
});
```

vdo player HTML

```
<div id="video-content-<?php  echo $vdoid; ?>" class=" ">
    <video id="video-player-<?php  echo $vdoid; ?>" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9 embed-responsive-item" controls preload="auto">
        <source src="/path/to/vdo/<?php  echo $vdoid; ?>.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
</div>
```

vdo player JS

```
function loadvjs(){
    var player = videojs('video-player-<?php  echo $vdoid; ?>',{
        playbackRates: [1,2,3],
        textTrackSettings: false,
    });
    player.ready(function() { 
        player.play();
    });
}
setTimeout(loadvjs, 1000); //bypass document ready that doesnt fire
```

The error return was "Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined" on the second line of the vdo player JS. The HTML5 video still loads and playable in native player.

Above code is able initialize videojs player if the video tag is placed on the page (not from ajax).

I'm try googling around, but couldn't find any answer to my case. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Are your scripts loaded in the correct order?